# What is the use of the css syntax used in below code?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Unable to understand the usage of below selector. Although this selector is
not displayed in inpect element

```
css code for my file


#header .navbar-brand [class*="icon"] {
background-color: #649300;
font-size: 30px;
color: #ffffff;
border-radius: 100%;
display: inline-block;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
text-align: center;
line-height: 50px;
position: relative;
left: -4px;
padding: 0;
top: auto;
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
-moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
-o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
-ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That selector is looking for an element with a class that contains the word "icon". It's a attribute wildcard selector.

So for example, anything like this would be selected.

```
class="icon-blue"
class="roundicon"
```

You also have other methods to perform this kind of check by using `^, $`

So the CSS  with `^` would look like this:

```
   [class^="icon"] {
    /* THIS SELECTS ANYTHING THAT BEGINS WITH ICON */
   }
```

This would select this type of class:

```
class="icon-blue"
class="icon-green"
class="iconbluegreen"
```

Then the dollar sign `$` in the selector would look like this:

```
   [class$="icon"] {
    /* THIS SELECTS ANYTHING THAT ENDS WITH ICON */
    }
```

And would select this type of class:

```
class="blue-icon"
class="green-icon"
class="bluegreenicon"
```

Comment: Thats great got it... thankyou

Comment: You have enough reputation that you should be searching to make sure the question is a duplicate before you post an answer for it.

Comment: cool, I'm just too eager to get a correct answer :) Ill check from now on.

Answer (score 1):

It's looking for html elements that contains ".icon" within the .navbar-brand within the #header.

Answer (score 1):

This is like id->header having class->navbar-brand inside that class all icon class